# woocommerce настройка отправки заказа на разные email

Tags: php, woocommerce, order

Добрый день!

Как отправлять на разные email адреса заказы, которые были оформлены в зависимости от категории, в которой лежит товар ?

Допустим есть:

Категория 1
Категория 2

И если заказ оформлен на товар, который принадлежит категории 1 отправлять на один email.

И наоборот, если заказ оформлен на товар, который принадлежит категории 2 отправлять на второй email.

Comment: А если в заказе 3 товара, и все из разных категорий?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решается таким фильтром получателя письма (добавьте код в functions.php вашей темы):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order_filter', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order_filter( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Измените $recipient на основании информации в $order
    return $recipient;
}
```

Второй аргумент в фильтре - текущий заказ. Выбирайте из него line_items (товары в заказе), определяйте их категории и вносите изменения в $recipient